# How to get id of anchor tag, regardless of where it is in hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I want to get the id/class/both of the anchor tag, regardless of where it falls in the tag hierarchy. Example below is strange but realistic for my purposes because our website is accessed through a CMS that I have no control over. If people add multiple levels of formatting at different times, the CMS likes to add new span's...

So, having the live with the above facts, I want to pin down specific anchor tags by their id/class/both, but I don't always know where they will be located in the tag drill-down.

```
<div id="div_id_A" class="div_class_A">
    <div class="div_class_A">
        <a href="#" id="anchor_id_A" class="anchor_class_A">
            <span class="span_class_A">
                <span id="span_id_B">
                    <span id="span_id_C" class="span_class_C">
                        <p>
                            Click Me
                        </p>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </span>
         </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

I have started off like such,

```
var dataLayer = dataLayer || [];

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var telm = event.target.parentNode.className;
    var delm = 'anchor_id_A';
    console.log(telm);
    if (telm == delm) {
        dataLayer.push({
            'youClicked': telm
        });
        console.log(dataLayer);
    };
});

*WHERE: telm = target element; delm = desired element.
```

To clarify. I am specifying anchor for a reason, it is not simply for the example. As I am restricted by our CMS, I can't go in and add markup to pre-defined code (i.e. template), but I do need to know what link was clicked as exactly as possible (for Google Analytics), so that I can track down what users are ignoring, not seeing, or prefering.

Comment: If you want a list of all anchor elements you can use `document.getElementsByTagName("a")` .. See this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp

Comment: Can you not just attach click handlers to all the <a> tags, then read this.id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can navigate up the hierarchy until you reach the anchor element, then just read its ID.

See here:

```js
var dataLayer = dataLayer || [];

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var el = event.target;
  while (el.parentElement && el.tagName != 'A') {
    el = el.parentElement;
  }
  dataLayer.push({
      'youClicked': el
  });
  console.log(dataLayer);
  alert(el.id);
});
```

```html
<div id="div_id_A" class="div_class_A">
  <div class="div_class_A">
    <a href="#" id="anchor_id_A" class="anchor_class_A">
      <span class="span_class_A">
        <span id="span_id_B">
          <span id="span_id_C" class="span_class_C">
            <p>Click Me</p>
          </span>
        </span>
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works exactly as desired. Tested with multiple unknowns.

Comment: Added if statement to filter out undesirables (whatever they are; for em they are whitespace clicks).

`document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

  var el = event.target;

  while (el.parentElement && el.tagName != 'A') {

    el = el.parentElement;

  }

  if (el.id != '') {

alert(el.id);

}

});
`
Sorry, not sure how to make the code above as a block.

Comment: @rorschaff, cool, so you're building a list of all those anchors, provided they do have an ID, right? (you can't make a comment code a block, but I see what you've added)

Answer (score -1):

What you're trying to achieve, is probably something like this :

```js
var dataLayer = [];

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var needle = 'anchor_class_A'; // The class of the element you're looking for
    var closest = event.target.closest("." + needle);
    if(closest && closest.id) {
        dataLayer.push({
            'youClicked': closest.id
        });
        alert(JSON.stringify(dataLayer, null, '\t'));
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="div_id_A" class="div_class_A">
    <div class="div_class_A">
        <a href="#" id="anchor_id_A" class="anchor_class_A">
            <span class="span_class_A">
                <span id="span_id_B">
                    <span id="span_id_C" class="span_class_C">
                        <p class="clicker">
                            Click Me
                        </p>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </span>
         </a>
     </div>
    <div class="div_class_A">
        <a href="#" id="anchor_id_X" class="anchor_class_A">
            <span class="span_class_A">
                <span id="span_id_Y">
                    <span id="span_id_Z" class="span_class_C">
                        <p class="clicker">
                            Click Me
                        </p>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </span>
         </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue is **finding** the proper anchor element, not **accessing** its ID.

Comment: @Shomz so what info do you have about your element? How can I recognize the right element if I don't know the ID? For example, f you know the class, you could use `document.getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: No, no, no... OP knows only the clicked element, and wants to find the anchor ID, which is somewhere up in the hierarchy... at least that's how I understood and wrote my answer.

Comment: @Shomz that is corret. In the end I will be using the script to access multiple different anchor in multiple different unknown hierarchies. If I had more control over the static DOM then I'd make it more me friendly.

Comment: @rorschaff : Check the last version of my code. I made quite a few edits, and I think it now does exactly what you want it to do!

Comment: So, in your latest version you already know the ID you're looking for (which of course you cannot know in the real code), then use the experimental method `closest` to actually retrieve that ID? And all that one hour after I gave the right answer and the code?

Comment: @Shomz : Wrong. I look by `CLASS`, not `ID`. More specificly, I look for an element that has the class `anchor_class_A`. This is pretty much the same behavior as in your answer, only you look by `TAG NAME`. My solution is actually more flexible, because the element doesn't have to be an `A` tag per se.

Comment: Nothing has been implemented yet. I will be trying both answers out until I make them fail. I accepted the above answer because it works for my question. Though, as @JohnSlegers pointed out, this answer can be more flexible. I will not argure with that, as I do not have enough JS knowledge to debate above my understanding.